# Capybara/Poltergeist can't select from a jQuery autocomplete field

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I have a problem with selecting from autocomplete field with Capybara.

I have next code:

```
def choose_autocomplete_result(text, input_id="input[data-autocomplete]")
  page.execute_script %Q{ $('#{input_id}').trigger("focus") }
  page.execute_script %Q{ $('#{input_id}').trigger("keydown") }
  sleep 1
  page.execute_script %Q{ $('.ui-menu-item a:contains("#{text}")').trigger("mouseenter").trigger("click"); }
end
```

And I have next test:

```
scenario 'Check autocomplete', js: true do
  find('.prop_address').native.send_keys 'lond'
  choose_autocomplete_result 'London', '.commercial_property_addresses_attributes_0_address'
  expect(page).to have_text('Some text')
end
```

And the error is:

```
Failure/Error: find('#output').find('div').trigger('click')

     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find css "#output"
```

Also I tried next test:

```
scenario 'Check autocomplete', js: true do
  fill_autocomplete('.prop_address', with: 'lond', select: 'London')
  expect(page).to have_text('Some text')
end
```

With next method:

```
def fill_autocomplete(css_id, options = {})
  find("#{css_id}").native.send_keys options[:with]
  page.execute_script %{ $('#{css_id}').trigger('focus') }
  page.execute_script %{ $('#{css_id}').trigger('keydown') }
  selector = %{ul.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item:contains("#{options[:select]}")}
  expect(page).to have_selector('ul.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item')
  page.execute_script %{ $('#{selector}').trigger('mouseenter').click() }
end
```

In this way error is:

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_selector('ul.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item')
       expected to find css "ul.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item" but there were no matches
```

In both variants the form is filled in with 'lond', but no one of the available variants is not selected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with all the execute_script stuff.  Assuming you're using the [jQueryUI autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) all that should be required is to send keys to the text input and then click on the shown choice. So your method should just be

```
def fill_autocomplete(css_selector, options = {})
  find(css_selector).send_keys options[:with]   # No .native. needed
  find("ul.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item", text: options[:select]).click()
end
```

Here's a gist you can run showing it working - https://gist.github.com/twalpole/a12aeef278c9c714b9e078ce2adfda99